# issue using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am experiencing a problem with using MFMailComposeViewController. Here's a sample code that I've tried to run on a device. I've deliberately added a delay of 5sec (just to simulate the experience of downloading a file for the attachment) after which app presents the "mail" controller. During the delay, if we click on the home button i.e make the app run in background and resume the app before 5 secs, the subject field will be blank and also the message body will have a value "message 1" and not "message 2" and if we minimize the app and resume the app after 5secs, subject doesn't appear but the body will be "message2" and not "message 1". Could you please help me out understand the behavior.

```
-(void) func:(MFMailComposeViewController *) mail
{
    [mail setMessageBody:@"message 2" isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];    
} 

- (IBAction)action:(id)sender 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController * mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mail setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [mail setMessageBody:@"message 1" isHTML:NO];
    [mail setSubject:@"subject 1"];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    
        [self performSelector:@selector(func:) withObject:mail afterDelay:5];     
  });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here You Go!

```
-(IBAction)email {
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
        [composer setSubject:@""];
        [composer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
        [composer release];
    }
    else
        [composer release];
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.